# Mysql is larger than wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

Wamp which includes mysql,php,apache is only 24.7 MB but the only Mysql is 207 MB [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WAMP environment, a developer is probably more focused on

- Coping PHP/Perl/Python
- Configuring Apache to get the WebServer going
- Using MySQL to store data, far less concern for the MySQL Utilities and other Bells and Whistles
- Getting Windows to coordinate the use of Apache, PHP, and MySQL (If you use IIS instead of Apache, that means the environment is a WIMP).

WAMP/LAMP environments was set up with this mind. MySQL would come with the bare essentials for installing MySQL and storing and backing up data. Such bare essential utilities may include:

- [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) : Command-Line Client Program
- [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) : For taking Textual Backups

MySQL comes with utilities for doing

- Replication
- Table Repair
- Load Testing (such as [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlslap.html))
- Reporting on Stats
- things like these (See all the [Major Utilities for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/programs-admin-utils.html))

If a serious Developer wants to be just as serious at prepping and optimizing the database as a Developer/DBA, then MySQL has everything a DBA could want in that bigger download. Downloading both would be just fine in that instance.